# How to get slug from an URL JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, next.js

I have the URLs for example.

- https://example.com/about?hl=en#iron
- https://example.com/product/roller/?hl=en&lo=true
- https://example.com/learn/goin/?hl=en&lo=true#iron

And I want to get these out to be string.

```
'about'
'product'
'learn'
```

I've tried. I use **Next.js** by the way.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const { asPath } = useRouter()

const result = asPath.substring(1).split('?')[0].split('#')[0].split('/')[0]
```

But are there a better way to deal with these like using `RegEx` or other methods?

And also looking forward to get like.

```
'about' or ['about']
'product/roller' or ['product','roller']
'learn/goin' or ['learn','goin']
```

Possible?

Comment: How about using `^http[s]?:\/\/.*?\/([^?\/]*)` regex, [Online demo for this regex](https://regex101.com/r/MyvgaF/1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an `URL` object, get the `pathname` and extract non-slashes

```js
let slug = url => new URL(url).pathname.match(/[^\/]+/g)

console.log(slug('https://example.com/about?hl=en#iron'))
console.log(slug('https://example.com/product/roller/?hl=en&lo=true'))
console.log(slug('https://example.com/learn/goin/?hl=en&lo=true#iron'))
```

A non-regex way would be `.pathname.split('/').filter(Boolean)`

Answer (score 3):

```
location.pathname.split('/').slice(1);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/pathname

Answer (score 0):

Although that's not the question, I see that your URLs are made up of parameters. They must be collected with `URLSearchParams` or `searchParams`:

```
let params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
let hl = params.get('hl');
let lo = params.get('lo');
```

Cf. MDN doc.